# .tramp_history files

Tags: files, tramp

I have noticed that opening a tramp connection on remote hosts sometimes created a .tramp_history file in the user's directory. Is there any way to disable such a behavior? I have to log in to many boxes and that's a lot of cleanup to do. No such options seem to be available in the tramp customization group.

The solution might certainly involve some lisp, but my skills are so far very limited... Thanks for your help!

PS: the same question was asked in 2011, see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-01/msg00875.html...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In recent Tramp versions, there is the variable `tramp-histfile-override`. You can override its default value.

Comment: How about elaborating a bit? How does this help answer the question?

Comment: The docstring explains this a little bit. `(setq tramp-histfile-override "/dev/null")` would avoid writing Tramp specific entries in a remote history file. However, there is an error in some bash versions which would give undesired results. Therefore, Tramp uses the default value ".tramp_history".

Comment: Is there anything else we need to do besides changing this value in tramp/lisp/tramp-sh.el and reloading init.el? Do we need to recompile anything?

Comment: Setting `tramp-histfile-override` shall be sufficient. It will be taken for every new connection.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the variable `tramp-persistency-file-name` is used by `tramp-dump-connection-properties` and is also hard-coded into settings that load initially with `tramp-cache.el`.  I would suggest changing the name/location to `/tmp/.tramp` or something of that nature if you don't want to ever see it.  There is no user option to turn it off completely.  Of course, the `/tmp` directory on some operating systems is emptied out each time the computer is started -- so bear that in mind when choosing a location.  A better idea is to set up folders for certain files that Emacs needs and store them in there.

```
(require 'tramp-cache)
(setq tramp-persistency-file-name "/tmp/.tramp")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm wondering if this file is absolutly necessary for tramp to function correctly (will be able to test later this weekend)... and if it could be redirected to /dev/null.