# Tramp recreates /dev/null as a regular file

Tags: tramp

The default tramp history file is /dev/null, which is a big problem because tramp recreates its history file as a regular file when it hits history limit, which is rather annoying.

I tried to override the path variable for the history file with:

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'tramp)
(defvar tramp-histfile-override "~/.tramp_history" "Prevent tramp from using /dev/null and recreating it as a regular file when history size is reached.")
```

according to: [.tramp_history files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12904/tramp-history-files)

I used defvar because there is no such a variable as tramp-histfile-override

and it is not working. Well the funny thing is that I know a solution:

Change the HISTFILE value from /dev/null to something more sane in tramp-sh.el

```
@@ -3865,7 +3865,7 @@ file exists and nonzero exit status otherwise."
       ;; the prompt in /bin/bash, it must be discarded as well.
       (tramp-send-command
        vec (format
-       "exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=/dev/null PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=%s PS2='' PS3='' %s %s"
+       "exec env ENV='' HISTFILE=~/.tramp_history PROMPT_COMMAND='' PS1=%s PS2='' PS3='' %s %s"
        (tramp-shell-quote-argument tramp-end-of-output)
        shell (or extra-args ""))
        t))
@@ -4587,7 +4587,7 @@ connection if a previous connection has died for some reason."
        (delete-process p))
          (setenv "TERM" tramp-terminal-type)
          (setenv "LC_ALL" "en_US.utf8")
-         (setenv "HISTFILE" "/dev/null")
+         (setenv "HISTFILE" "~/.tramp_history")
          (setenv "PROMPT_COMMAND")
          (setenv "PS1" tramp-initial-end-of-output)
          (let* ((target-alist (tramp-compute-multi-hops vec))
```

Question: Are there any other ways without modifying the Emacs source code?

Comment: As this bug has been fixed upstream, upgrading Emacs would be a way...

Comment: ... and if you don't want to upgrade the whole Emacs, upgrading Tramp to the latest stable version 2.2.13 would fix it also ...

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Thanks I patched my recent version, and it works fine.